# R store output from lapply with multiple functions

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I'm using lapply to loop through a list of dataframes and apply the same set of functions.  This works fine when lapply has just one function, but I'm struggling to see how I store/print the output from multiple functions - in that case, I seem to only get output from one 'loop'.

So this:

```
output <- lapply(dflis,function(lismember) vss(ISEQData,n=9,rotate="oblimin",diagonal=F,fm="ml"))
```

works, while the following doesn't:

```
output <- lapply(dflis,function(lismember){
outputvss <- vss(lismember,n=9,rotate="oblimin",diagonal=F,fm="ml")
nefa <- (EFA.Comp.Data(Data=lismember, F.Max=9, Graph=T))
})
```

I think this dummy example is an analogue, so in other words:

```
nbs <- list(1==1,2==2,3==3,4==4)
nbsout <- lapply(nbs,function(x) length(x))
```

Gives me something I can access, while I can't see how to store output using the below (e.g. the attempt to use nbsout[[x]][2]):

```
nbs <- list(1==1,2==2,3==3,4==4)
nbsout <- lapply(nbs,function(x){
  nbsout[[x]][1]<-typeof(x)
  nbsout[[x]][2]<-length(x)
  }
                 )
```

I'm using RStudio and will then be printing outputs/knitting html (where it makes sense to display the results from each dataset together, rather than each function-output for each dataset sequentially).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should return a structure that include all your outputs.  Better to return a named list. You can also return a data.frame if your outputs have all the same dimensions.

```
otutput <- lapply(dflis,function(lismember){
    outputvss <- vss(lismember,n=9,rotate="oblimin",diagonal=F,fm="ml")
    nefa <- (EFA.Comp.Data(Data=lismember, F.Max=9, Graph=T))

    list(outputvss=outputvss,nefa=nefa)  
    ## or data.frame(outputvss=outputvss,nefa=nefa) 
})
```

When you return a data.frame you can use `sapply` that simply outputs the final result to a big data.frame. Or you can use the classical:

```
do.call(rbind,output)
```

to aggregate the result.

Answer (score 2):

A function should always have an explicit return value, e.g.

```
output <- lapply(dflis,function(lismember){
   outputvss <- vss(lismember,n=9,rotate="oblimin",diagonal=F,fm="ml")
   nefa <- (EFA.Comp.Data(Data=lismember, F.Max=9, Graph=T))
   #return value:
   list(outputvss, nefa)
})
```

`output` is then a list of lists.

Comment: I guess it will be easier to access the values if they would use `c` instead of `list` (at least for their reproducible example, when the result is just one value per function)

Comment: @DavidArenburg `c` is just a shortcut for a `list`, isn't?

Comment: @agstudy, the output is a vector per each argument within the list,  instead of list per each argument within the list. Try `lapply(nbs, function(x){ nbsout1<-typeof(x) ; nbsout2<-length(x); c(nbsout1, nbsout2)})`

Comment: @DavidArenburg but you assume that the 2 has the same dimensions , indeed `c` will unlist the result to get the same vector ....

Comment: @DavidArenburg Maybe. This is just an example. I have no idea what kind of objects `outputvss` and `nefa` are.

Comment: @agstudy I didn't assume anything. I just said that *for the provided reproducible example*, this would result in much more convenient output.